# Multi-Scale Template Matching without looping through every size

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, matchtemplate

What are the different ways to Match an image to a template on different size screens?
For instance, if I have a template from a 720p screen and try to use it on a 1080p screen it would never find it
I tried Sift before, but there were way too many false positives. And changing the size of the template to match every size screen is way too heavy for what I'm doing.
I need to check a frame at least 10 times a second

Comment: Don’t you know the screen size? I would suggest you add more information about what you are actually trying to do. Are you matching a logo on video maybe? Is the template a binary mask, or grey-value, or color?

Comment: I can find the screen size actually. But, I don't know if the icon is in a window and being resized or not. I'm interested in what would be the step if say it is full screen though.
The template is a grey value, i'm using Canny Edge detection to match it

Comment: One suggestion is to use pyramidal scaling

Answer (score 0):

1. OpenCV have a template matching function [here](https://docs.opencv.org/master/df/dfb/group__imgproc__object.html#ga586ebfb0a7fb604b35a23d85391329be)
2. This approah is quite naive but have you try either to use a super resolution based on a deep learning (such as [this one](https://github.com/tensorlayer/srgan)) or to interpolate the resolution of your test image to the size of the mask ? 
   You can also take a look to [matchShapes](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gaadc90cb16e2362c9bd6e7363e6e4c317)
3. Among all the features detector algorithm have you investigate other algorithms than SIFT ? Take a look to [enter link description here](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d5/d51/group__features2d__main.html) and you have the contribution modules [there](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d7a/group__xfeatures2d__experiment.html).